# @JoinColumn issue regarding the reference

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have a simple ER

[image]

I'm using `@JoinColumn` to get the model

```
@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="dealer_id",referencedColumnName="dealer_id")
AddressModel addressModel;
```

So based on dealer_id I'm fetching the relevant address.

but Query formed by hibernate is

```
Hibernate: 
select
    addressmod0_.add_id as add_id1_0_0_,
    addressmod0_.custom as custom2_0_0_,
    addressmod0_.dealer_id as dealer_i3_0_0_,
    addressmod0_.district as district4_0_0_,
    addressmod0_.pincode as pincode5_0_0_,
    addressmod0_.state as state6_0_0_,
    addressmod0_.taluka as taluka7_0_0_,
    addressmod0_.village as village8_0_0_ 
from
    address addressmod0_ 
where
    addressmod0_.add_id=?
```

The reference should be dealer_id and not add_id. Don't know why such wrong query is formed despite of giving the different reference.
Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: You need to use @JoinColumn in AddressModel as you are storing foreign key in that table

Comment: That really helped..